# jquery html() problems in CHROME

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe

I have an Iframe inside my HTML.
From that Iframe I'm accesing to the parent window to retrieve the HTML code of a DIV with an ID=result

Everything works in FF3, FF5 and IE8, but not in Chrome 12.
Code in Iframe is:

```
message = $(document, parent.window.document).contents().find('#resultsubmit').html();
```

However, if I remove html() method Chrome yes is returning a valid object (html object)

But as soon as I add html() to read de html inside an error happens.

Any clue about that?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var message = $(parent.window.document).contents().find('#message').html();
$('#target').html(message);
```

Comment: Maybe I explained wrong: I'm trying to retrieve the contents of message (var message = $(parent.window.document).contents().find('#message').html();)<-- problem is this line in Chrome is returning NULL instead of some text as in FF and IE.